# Postgres SQL Server fails to start in Windows 8

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am getting the following error while starting the postgresql server service.
[image]

I was working in the system, but suddenly the service gone. How can I trace the issue. Im using the version 9.6

Answer (score 1):

You must read the logs. In windows you can check the event viewer and the postgres log file as defined in the postgresql.conf.

> On Windows, eventlog is also supported. Set this parameter to a list
>   of desired log destinations separated by commas. The default is to log
>   to stderr only. This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf
>   file or on the server command line.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html